# Can't enable middleware CORS in Laravel 5.1.46

Tags: php, laravel-5, cors

I'm struggling with this issue, i have an API made in Laravel, one of endpoints needs to be accesible to others servers that make a request, i read several forums, here, i and could'nt find a solution.

This the error that throws me in the front:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/auth/signup' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

i tried to implement a cors middleware, this is the code:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CORS {

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

        // ALLOW OPTIONS METHOD
        $headers = [
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'=> 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'=> 'Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Origin'
        ];
        if($request->getMethod() == "OPTIONS") {
            // The client-side application can set only headers allowed in Access-Control-Allow-Headers
            return Response::make('OK', 200, $headers);
        }

        $response = $next($request);
        foreach($headers as $key => $value)
            $response->header($key, $value);
        return $response;
    }
}
```

in kernel.php:

```
 protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
```

in the routes.php:

```
Route::post('api/v1/auth/signup', 'Api\AuthApiController@signUpUser')->middleware(['cors']);
```

Why the cors middleware is not doing nothing?
From the server side there's no errors.

Comment: Is there a reason why you aren't using an existing off the shelf package for this?

Comment: @MatthewDaly Also i already tried barryvdh/laravel-cors, but didn't work, first it was some uncompatibilty with some dependencies (which i can't change , i don't have permission to modify those), then tried with an older  version, that didn't work too.

Comment: That's really messed up. Your boss doesn't want you using third party packages, yet presumably is OK with you using Laravel, which is made up of a load of third party packages. I imagine that the problem installing `barryvdh/laravel-cors` is due to Laravel 5.1 no longer being supported. I'd be inclined to at least consider upgrading to the current Laravel LTS version, 5.5, which isn't too hard.